# Error while saving trained SVM in OpenCV 3.2.0 Java

Tags: java, svm, opencv3.1

when I try to save my trained SVM into file, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: unknown exception
at org.opencv.core.Algorithm.save_0(Native Method)
at org.opencv.core.Algorithm.save(Algorithm.java:53)
at signdetectiontool.training.Trainer.createTrainingFile(Trainer.java:275)
at signdetectiontool.controller.MainController.trainNetworkAction(MainController.java:372)
... 58 more
```

I am using OpenCV 3.2.0 Java version. Has anyone encountered such problem? I am pretty sure that my SVM is well trained, because train method returned "true" and also predicting with it seems to work well. Are there any known solutions/workarounds for this problem?

Saving looks like any other examples:

```
svmClassifier.save("svmdata.xml");
```

Comment: Haven't you still solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround might be to save your training data manually and each time you want to use your classifier train it again. It depends on how much data you have and if the overhead can be ignored or not.